# Issue when using "woocommerce_product_get_stock_quantity" filter hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce, stock

I want to replace the stock quantity on the single product page with "5+", if the stock quantity is more than 5, else display the original quantity.

I tried to modify the hook as below

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_stock_quantity' ,'custom_get_stock_quantity', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_stock_quantity' ,'custom_get_stock_quantity', 10, 2 );
function custom_get_stock_quantity( $value, $_product ) {
    global $product;

    if($_product->get_stock_quantity() > 5){
     return "5+";
    }
    else{
        return $_product->get_stock_quantity();
    }
}
```

This gives me 502 server error. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is due to several reasons

- Hook is deprecated
- Your callback function only returns a number: `5`, not a string: `"5+"`
- By using `$_product->get_stock_quantity()` you create an infinite loop, since this function calls the hook

So to meet your demand, you will have to approach this differently. For example by using the `woocommerce_get_availability_text` hook

So you get:

```php
// Availability text
function filter_woocommerce_get_availability_text( $availability, $product ) {
    if ( $product->get_stock_quantity() > 5 ) {
        $availability = '+5';
    }

    return $availability; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'filter_woocommerce_get_availability_text', 10, 2 );
```